proving the set of natural numbers is infinite (Tao Ex 2.6.3)
Tao's Analysis I 4th ed has the following exercise 3.6.3:

Let $n$ be a natural number, and let $f:\{i \in \mathbb{N}:i \leq i \leq n\} \to \mathbb{N}$ be a function. Show that there exists a natural number $M$ such that $f(i) \leq M$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$. (Hint: induct on $n$. You may also want to peel at Lemma 5.1.14.). Thus finite subsets of the natural numbers are bounded. Use this to give an alternate proof of Theorem 3.6.12 that does not use Lemma 3.6.9.

Showing that a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is bounded can be done by induction, and isn't too difficult (unless I am in error).
The final part of the exercise asks us to prove Theorem 3.6.12 which is:

The set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ is infinite.

Question: I can't see how to start with a statement that a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is bounded, and conclude the infinitude of the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$. I'd welcome some guidance.

Discussion
The best candidate for an argument I can find is the contrapositive:
If a set is not bounded, then it is infinite (in cardinality).
Then I can show that for any number $n \in \mathbb{N}$ I can find a larger one using the Peano axiom about each natural having a successor. Therefore, this set $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded. And therefore, using the above contrapositive statement, it must have infinite cardinality.
Is this correct? It feels wrong.
Tao's book defines a finite set as one with $n \in \mathbb{N}$ cardinality, and infinite otherwise. He defines a set having cardinality $n$ if there is a bijection with the set $\{1, \ldots, n\}$. We don't use this in the above argument.

What does it mean for an arbitrary set to be bounded? Why not use the definition and the above exercise? Suppose $\mathbb{N}$ is finite. Then you have a bijection $f:{1\leq i \leq n} \to \mathbb{N}$. Can you see how the exercise contradicts this?

@MaikPickl To be clear, the contradiction is the bijection? Because $\mathbb{N}$ has more elements than ${1 \leq i \leq n}$. Is that correct? If so, I would need to show  $\mathbb{N}$  has more elements.

It's basically what you and Davide already said. Suppose you have a bijection $f$, then by the exercise you know that there exists a $M$ s.t. $f(i)\leq M$ for all $i \in {1,\ldots,n}$. But that means that the successor of $M$  can't be in the image of $f$. A contradiction to $f$ being a bijection.

If $\mathbb{N}$ was finite, then it would be bounded by the first part of the exercise (it would be a finite set containing the first $M$ natural numbers; you can choose f to be the inclusion map). In particular the maximum $M$ of this set would exist (you can always find the maximum in finite sets), and it would definitely be a natural number. As you said, though $M+1$ is also a natural number which is larger than the maximum, a contradiction. What you claimed looks correct to me. Anyway, I think you made a typo at the beginning of your question: $f:\{1 \leq i \leq n\} \to \mathbb{N}$.

to be clear, are you saying my argument is correct? That is, the Peano axioms tell me for any natural number, I can find a successor, and so the set of natural numbers is not bounded, and therefore by the contrapositive statement, it is infinite. (Sorry I am a beginner and I find this hard)

Yeah it looks perfectly fine to me

EDIT: Just to be clear, a satisfying answer probably depends on how deep into logic you want to dive. A very rigorous proof, which makes use of Peano axioms as they are, could be to observe that the successor function is an injection (by axiom P3) but not a surjection (by axiom P4) from $\mathbb{N}$ to itself, which would be impossible if $\mathbb{N}$ was finite, as any injection from a finite set to itself is also a surjection (and thus a bijection).

This is solution I wrote up thanks to everyone's help: We have shown: a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is finite, then it is bounded.
The contrapositive: If a subset of the $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded, then it is not finite.
Consider the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$. Let's assume it is bounded, and that $M$ is a bound. This $M$ is a natural number, and by the Peano axioms, has a successor $M+1$ which is also a natural number. Therefore $M$ was not the bound. We have shown that $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded. By the above contrapositive statement, it is therefore not finite. $\square$

Since we want to prove it is infinite, we do not assume it is bounded, we assume it is finite to find a contradiction. Then it follows it is bounded and you can go on with your proof.

Thanks Davide, I've also updated with $M$ "largest element" rather than "bound": Consider the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$. Assume it is finite. That means it must be bounded. Let's say $M$ is the largest element in that set. This $M$ is a natural number, and by the Peano axioms, has a successor $M+1$ which is also a natural number. Therefore $M$ can't be the largest element in $\mathbb{N}$. We have shown $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded, therefore not finite.

Let me stress that the logic flaw here is that you should actually prove that $M+1$ is not an element of ${1,...,M}$, since otherwise $M+1$ could be smaller than or equal to the maximum $M$ of $\mathbb{N}$ and no contradiction appears. However, I guess this was not how the problem was intended to be solved, since this is rather a logic discussion more than an Analysis I exercise. In conclusion, I suggest being careful when saying "by Peano axioms", because the argument becomes much more delicate. In this context I find it reasonable to use the simple idea that $M+1>M$. Hope I was clear!

Hi  Davide - this is interesting, and Terence Tao's approach is indeed to encourage us to think axiomatically during the first few chapters. Therefore I think your point is very valid. I think at this point in the book we have the Peano axioms and the ZF axioms. But I don't think the book has stated "n++" is actually larger than "n" (ordinal vs cardinal). The next chapter covers the integers and I guess that is where we cover orderings like > and <. So given that, how would one prove M++ is outside 1..M?

PS Davide I really appreciate your patience and willingness to help :)

I don't know if this can help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4297029/how-to-prove-that-there-are-n-natural-numbers-that-are-less-or-equal-than-n

if every finite set of natural numbers is bounded by a natural number then if you assume the set of natural numbers is finite then it is bounded say by R  but since R is a natural number then R+1 is a natural number and thus the set that you initially defined does not contain all natural numbers thus contradiction hence there are infintely many natural numbers. note its very important to pay attention that the argument here is that every finite set of natural number is bounded! do not be confused that by using the induction argument to prove that a finite set of natural numbers is bounded you are somewhat using a circular argument since the induction principle involves an induction of N. the way you prove a finite set of natural numbers is bounded is irrelevant once you assume you have a result and try to reach a contradiction which is what i assume is the purpose of the exercise here. hope this helps

thank you this is very helpful.

@Penelope you are very much welcome. glad i could help :)
